# npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I am trying to update react and react-dom from 17.0.2 to 18.0.2 in a component library project.

I get an error `npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency`

The peerDependency is react@">=16.3".

18.0.2 >= 16.3, so why would this be an error?

```
$> npm install --save-dev --save-exact react@18.0.2 react-dom@18.0.2

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: my-lib@1.0.8
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.3" from @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome
npm WARN     dev @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@"0.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   12 more (@restart/context, @restart/hooks, prop-types-extra, ...)
```